# Error de conversión nvarchar a date desde excel a sql

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

Tengo un excel que se conecta a sql mediante Microsoft query, ejecutando un store procedure con 3 parámetros, 2 de ellos son del tipo fecha, cuando estos parámetros los cargo en las propiedades de la conexión la consulta anda normalmente pero cuando esos datos son tomados desde 2 celdas del excel el mismo me da un error de conversión de nvarchar a date, cambie el formato de la celdas a fecha y me sigue pasando lo mismo.

Adjunto imagenes y codigo fuente del Store Procedure.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[HorasPorAplicacion] 
@fechaDesde date = null,
@fechaHasta date = null,
@proyecto varchar(50) = NULL
AS


    set @fechaHasta = GETDATE()

    SELECT a.Aplicativos,sum(a.Tiempo) Horas from (

        SELECT
                (SELECT
                        cfo.customvalue
                        FROM jira_new.dbo.customfieldvalue cfv
                        LEFT JOIN jira_new.dbo.customfieldoption cfo
                                ON cfv.customfield = cfo.customfield
                                AND cfv.stringvalue = CONVERT(varchar, cfo.id)
                        WHERE cfv.CUSTOMFIELD = 10513
                        AND cfv.issue = JI.id) Aplicativos,

                CONVERT(NUMERIC(7,2),(WL.timeworked / 3600)) Tiempo

        FROM jira_new.dbo.worklog WL
        INNER JOIN jira_new.dbo.jiraissue JI
                ON WL.issueid = JI.ID
        INNER JOIN jira_new.dbo.project PR
                ON PR.ID = JI.PROJECT
         WHERE 
             (WL.startdate between @fechaDesde and @fechaHasta)
            and (pr.pname = @proyecto OR @proyecto IS NULL)
            ) a
        group by 
            Aplicativos
        ORDER BY horas DESC
```

Comment: Probaste de pasarlos al SP como varchar y en el SP convertirlos a DATE?

Comment: No lo probe, necesitaba tratar de realizarlo primero sin modificar el Store Procedure ya que es consultado por otras app

Comment: Hay que empezar a hacer pruebas, para ver de que manera te puede funcionar. Intenta escribiendo las fechas en este formato  YYYYMMDD 20170101 en vez de 01/01/2017 haber si te sigue mostrando el mismo error

Comment: De esa manera me anduvo, nunca pensé que me andaría así!